# loading gif ajax implemenation in jsp

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

in my **jspx the implementation of loading gif**

when a list drop down is selected is as below

```
<ui:composition>

<style type="text/css">#mask {display: none;cursor: wait;z-index: 99999;position:absolute;top: 0;left: 0;height: 100%;width: 100%; background-color: white;filter: alpha(opacity = 50); }
</style>

<div id="mask"><div style="position: absolute; top : 300px; left :550px; text-align : center; vertical-align: middle;font-family:arial,helvetica,verdana,sans-serif; color : red;font-size : 16px;font-weight : bold; text-decoration: underline;"><img id="ajaxBusyImage" src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/progress.gif" />
<br/>loading</div></div>onchange="resetAllCheckBoxes();refreshAllActionButtons(#{myBean.selectedRotate.rotateReadOnly});showCursor();
```

showCursor() method is as below

```
function showCursor() {
document.getElementById('mask').style.display = 'block';
return false;
}
```

I need to implement the same in jsp file

when I tried to include  in , its giving me error that its not right place to include.

How can I correct it or there is another **way of implementing it in jsp?**

I included  inside the  and onChange calling a method showCursor()

```
<div id="mask"><div style="position: absolute; top : 300px; left : 550px; text-align : center; vertical-align: middle;font-family: arial,helvetica,verdana,sans-serif; color : red; font-size : 16px; font-weight : bold; text-decoration: underline;"><img src="../images/blank.gif" /><br/>loadinggg</div></div>
```

--- update I have removed image id and given source as the path. Now error has been eliminated but the image is present when the page is first launched and the gif is not as the real gif...just as an icon of an image.

I am still not getting the gif working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the id in img tag and give src as
`<img scr= "/images/blank.gif">` by placing the gif in the images folder.